# Looking for journal (without fees) to publish a research paper in Euclidean geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, journals

I am looking for a place to publish a research paper in Euclidean geometry. This is a fairly lengthy article (56 pages) in which I present a fundamental property of polygons. I have already been rejected in many journals, and all of them recognize that it is a valuable work, but that it is not suitable for their magazine. The last to refuse my job, after almost two and a half months of delay, was Annales of Henry Lebesgue (AHL). To exemplify the type of justifications that usually accompany the rejection of the work, I add this excerpt from the last **Referee report on the manuscript** from AHL:

"... The paper under review contains an observation in affine geometry that
does not seem to be studied before (at least to my knowledge). It is written
in great detail, with many beautiful figures, however in a somewhat verbose
style. A more concise definition and statement of the main result in the
beginning instead of the quite slow and cryptic exposition of the triangle
case would maybe have been helpful for the reader.
Even though the paper is of interest, it is clearly not suitable for a top tier
generalist journal as the Annales Henri Lebesgue, hence I cannot recommend
its publication and suggest submission to a journal more specialized in affine geometry. "

I am a retired professor and I no longer aspire to increase my curriculum vitae, but I find it disappointing that it was difficult to make available to the scientific community a work that has involved many hours of work and that, without a doubt, exposes an amazing result that lay. encrypted in the deep foundations of Geometry.

I would appreciate any suggestions that help me to bring this work to light, to make it known from a worthy place. Of course, I am not willing to pay fees to publish in open access.

Comment: if you wish to make your results available to the scientific community, wouldn't arXiv suffice? It is free, it is "open access", the only thing you would miss out on is the stamp of approval from a referee, but I understand from your message that this is not something you would miss.

Comment: Possibly https://jcgeometry.org/ , if it still is active. (Forum Geometricorum has been discontinued, alas.) For smaller papers with an olympiad flair, [Crux Mathematicorum](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/) is also an option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices, Carlo Beenakker and Darij Grinberg. I have published some work on arXiv, but I have not had good experiences on that site. They tend to reject jobs without much judgment. That is the reason why viXra was created, as a counterpoint to arXiv.

As for jcgeometry.org, the work does not meet the format conditions since they only accept black and grayscale images and my images are in color (necessary to differentiate different parts in a complex geometric construction), and I think that also exceeds the allowable size.

Comment: I think publishing on ResearchGate (RG) avoids many hours of manuscript formatting, wasted time, and anger when your work is rejected without much judgment.

Well, I will just wait to see if it is accepted to publish it as a book by a publisher that has invited me to publish with them, because as an article it is a bit long, and if not, I will directly upload it to RG, since it is already much prestigious and a big open-source of research articles for all the global researchers.

Comment: Looking at the answer of AHL, it seems that there is place for you to publish your text in a mathematical journal. ArXiv is a place to put preprints, there is no judgement on the quality, only administrative requirements. Researchgate is essentially the Facebook of mathematics, and is not really a place to publish, but to make reference to published work. On this webpage you have plenty of nice journals, completely free: https://www.cimpa.info/en/node/62 . I might take time, but this deserves it.

Another possibility would be the following journal: https://geombina.uccs.edu

Comment: Thank you Jérémy for your useful information and the time you have dedicated to me. But an additional difficulty is that each site requires a particular, non-standardized format; in some sites, they may accept a manuscript for consideration in a different format than the final for publication, but in others, they require that the initial document be adjusted to the site's format, and this is really dissuasive since it is a huge work of without any guarantee of acceptance.

Comment: It is quite contradictory that the effort to obtain a valuable result in the investigation is not only not rewarded but its altruistic publication is hindered. We will continue swimming against the current.

Comment: https://www.zbmath.org/serials/?q=Geometry

Comment: Interesting site! Thank you very much, Toni Mhax.